# Remove email field in devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to NOT require email for signing only mobile number to register user and login in using devise gem. I removed email from config/initializers/devise.rb:

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address, you can use `mobile number` instead of `username`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [link](https://github.com/welcu/devise/blob/e8b01c1677047328d947f297123d34183588ef81/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) to the validate.rb file of devise. You can see a method email_required? in the model. So I guess

```
 def email_required?
    false
 end
```

You need to put above method in your model.rb file.

You'll also need to make a slight modification to your users table. By default, Devise does not allow the email field to be null. Create and run change a migration that allows email to be null

```
 # in console
 rails g migration AddChangeColumnNullToUserEmail

 # migration file
class AddChangeColumnNullToUserEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true 
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => false 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address) guide, except use `mobile` instead of `username`. e.g.

In devise.rb:

```
config.authentication_keys = [:mobile]
```

In your controller:

```
.permit(:mobile)
```

Change the email field to your mobile field in `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

In devise.en.yml:

```
invalid: 'Invalid mobile number or password.'
not_found_in_database: 'Invalid mobile number or password.'
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement of @divyang's answers. You should also remove de `email's` index on `users` table...

```
remove_index "users", name: "index_users_on_email"
```